# Need to get value from a textbox in salesforce Lightning using jquery

Tags: jquery, salesforce-lightning

**What I have Tried**

Am having a cshtml page where there is a input type textbox and a button, I have created a event click function for the button and am trying to get the textbox value on button click, am getting undefined

**Code**

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:mybuttonclick()" />
function mybuttonclick() {
    var sdf = $("#myText").val();
    alert(sdf);
}
```

**Lightning Component**

```
<input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey"/>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue, sorry if this is a duplicate question

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, everything works just fine when i test it

Comment: Then why am getting undefined  ? @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: <input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey"/>
this is in Lightning component

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen the link which you gave is in apex, I need it in Lightning

Comment: Not sure about *salesfore* development environment, but have you wrapped the JavaScript code in script tag ?

Comment: @Shubanker yeah I have done it man, if not the code won't run and i won't be getting undefined at all